# What is wrong with my navbar?

Tags: html, css

For some reason my navbar is bigger than it's supposed to be. Or atleast I think it's my navbar. Whenever I remove `#rect` It goes away. What's the problem here?

```css
#tagline {
  font-style: italic;
  padding-right: 150px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

nav {
  background-color: white;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#logo {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

li, li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

li>a:hover {
  background-color: #7bcc1d;
  color: white;
}

.active { 
  background-color: #7bcc1d;
  color: white;
}

#main-bg {
  background-image: url('https://s15.postimg.org/ra1dhmjkb/main-bg.png');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
}

#rect {
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

span {
  margin: 0;
}

#enroll_button {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  background-color: #7bcc1d;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="https://s12.postimg.org/n0yt5tenx/lb_logo.png" id="logo" alt="logo">
  <span id="tagline">Live, 1-to-1, flexible and personalized</span>
  <ul id="nav-items">
   <li><a href="#">How it Works</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Teachers</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="active">Enroll</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>

 <div id="main-bg">
  <div id="rect">
   <h2>3 Steps to Complete<br>Your High School Foreign<br>Language Requirement</h2><br>
   <span><strong>Convenient Scheduling: </strong>Pick lessons<br>to fit your schedule.</span><br><br>
   <span><strong>Interactive Courses: </strong>Learn through<br>live, personal lessons.</span><br><br>
   <span><strong>Earn Approved Credits: </strong>Earn credits<br>to satisfy high school requirements.</span><br><br>
   <a href="#" id="enroll_button">Enroll in Your Course</a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set `#rect` as a block element and the `h2` margin is pulling the whole thing down.

```
#rect h2{margin-top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because of margins which set in user agent stylesheet from the browser. You can link the [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) and set your desire margins in your own css.